# How to convert HJM model risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$ to real measure $\mathbb{P}$?

Tags: interest-rates, risk-neutral-measure

HJM model, $df(t,T) = \mu(t,T) dt + \xi (t, T)dW(t)$, is  defined in risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$, according to Brigo's "Interest Rate Models" book.

I wonder, how could I transform it to  real measure $\mathbb{P}$? Is it mentioned in any book?

Comment: May I ask you why ?  I use this kind of model for pricing, so I only bother about Q. Why would you need it under P ?

Comment: @lmorin as an exercise on numeraire change? maybe i'm a bit too curious... ?